# Is WebSphere MQ the default JMS provider in WebSphere AS 8 / 8.5?

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

For tests of JMS in WebSphere I have downloaded the developer version of WebSphere AS 8.0.

Is WebSphere MQ (which is available as a separate product from IBM) already included in this version, or does WAS use a different JMS provider?

---

Update: I know that in the (Apache Geronimo based) IBM WASCE (the 'community edition'), Apache ActiveMQ is used as the default JMS provider.

Which product is used in WAS 8.0 / 8.5, a proprietary IBM product or an open source product like ActiveMQ as suggested in the answer below?

Comment: WAS and WMQ are sold as separate products, therefore WAS uses it's internal provider as the default.  If you are interested in WMQ there's a trial download on [developerWorks](http://bit.ly/fLeeQz).  Also, if your organization has a paid version of WebSphere Broker, you are [entitled to put it](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bh25920_.htm), including WMQ, on developer desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websphere AS comes with its own JMS provider as required by Java EE 6.

The provider isn't MQ. It could be a modified version of ActiveMQ or any other JMS compliant implementation.

Comment: Just telling that it comes with its own JMS provider as required by java ee 6. Its not MQ. I'm not sure though which one it is. It could be a modified version of ActiveMQ.

Comment: Exactly. I will move part of the comment up to the answer. :)

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question to "Which product is the default JMS provider (...)'?

Comment: Actually you don't really care. You use JMS in your code against the default api and you find everything you need for the configuration in the documentation. You may find some examples on IBMs DeveloperWorks as well.

Comment: I am interested in WebSphere MQ because of its support for some non-Java protocols

Comment: Then you have to buy MQ and code against the MQ apis/libs. You can run MQ without a WAS.

Comment: SIB (the JMS provider in WAS) allows you to connect to MQ. It is also possible to connect to SIB with non-Java clients after configuring WMQ client channel (there are some limitations though).

Answer (score 9):

WebSphere Application Server comes with a JMS provider called `Service Integration Bus (SIBus)`. This is also know as the default messaging provider of WebSphere Application Provider and is Java EE compliant messaging engine. It has features like
1) Clustering
2) Supports both P2P and Pub/Sub style of messaging.
3) High Availability
4) Security
5) And can integrate with WebSphere MQ.